# SQL grouping and running total of open items for a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table of items that, for sake of simplicity, contains the `ItemID`, the `StartDate`, and the `EndDate` for a list of items.

```
ItemID     StartDate     EndDate
1          1/1/2011      1/15/2011
2          1/2/2011      1/14/2011
3          1/5/2011      1/17/2011
...
```

My goal is to be able to join this table to a table with a sequential list of dates, 
and say both how many items are open on a particular date, and also how many items are cumulatively open.

```
Date      ItemsOpened     CumulativeItemsOpen
1/1/2011  1               1
1/2/2011  1               2
...
```

I can see how this would be done with a `WHILE` loop, 
but that has performance implications. I'm wondering how 
this could be done with a set-based approach?

Comment: can you please redefine what you mean by ItemsOpened and ItemsOpenedCumulative? You accepted an answer that suggests that ItemsOpened = "Number of items Opened on this date" and ItemsOPenedCumulative = "Number of Items currently open".  I'd like to delete my answer if it is incorrect

Comment: Good point; my column naming left room for confusion. "Number of items currently open" is what I was looking for.

Comment: Are you referring to the Cumulative column or the ItemsOpened column? Thanks

Comment: One last thing, does "ItemsOpened" mean "ItemsOpenedOnThisDay"? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, "ItemsOpened" does mean "ItemsOpenedOnThisDay".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN d.CheckDate = i.StartDate THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
         AS ItemsOpened
     , COUNT(i.StartDate)
         AS ItemsOpenedCumulative
FROM Dates AS d
  LEFT JOIN Items AS i
    ON d.CheckDate BETWEEN i.StartDate AND i.EndDate
GROUP BY d.CheckDate
```

Answer (score 2):

This may give you what you want

```
SELECT DATE, 
    SUM(ItemOpened) AS ItemsOpened, 
    COUNT(StartDate) AS ItemsOpenedCumulative
FROM
    (
    SELECT d.Date, i.startdate, i.enddate,
        CASE WHEN i.StartDate = d.Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ItemOpened
    FROM Dates d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Items i ON d.Date BETWEEN i.StartDate AND i.EndDate
    ) AS x
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

This assumes that your date values are DATE data type.  Or, the dates are DATETIME with no time values.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this useful. The recusive part can be replaced with a table. To demonstrate it works I had to populate some sort of date table. As you can see, the actual sql is short and simple.

```
DECLARE @i table (itemid INT, startdate DATE, enddate DATE)

INSERT @i VALUES (1,'1/1/2011', '1/15/2011') 
INSERT @i VALUES (2,'1/2/2011', '1/14/2011')
INSERT @i VALUES (3,'1/5/2011', '1/17/2011') 

DECLARE @from DATE
DECLARE @to DATE
SET @from = '1/1/2011'
SET @to = '1/18/2011'

-- the recusive sql is strictly to make a datelist between @from and @to
;WITH cte(Date) 
AS ( 
SELECT @from DATE 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, DATE) 
FROM cte ch     
WHERE DATE < @to 
) 
SELECT cte.Date, sum(case when cte.Date=i.startdate then 1 else 0 end) ItemsOpened, count(i.itemid) ItemsOpenedCumulative 
FROM cte 
left join @i i on cte.Date between i.startdate and i.enddate
GROUP BY cte.Date
OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2005+, you could use a [recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to obtain running totals, with the additional help of the [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), like this:

```
WITH grouped AS (
  SELECT
    d.Date,
    ItemsOpened = COUNT(i.ItemID),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.Date)
  FROM Dates d
    LEFT JOIN Items i ON d.Date BETWEEN i.StartDate AND i.EndDate
  GROUP BY d.Date
  WHERE d.Date BETWEEN @FilterStartDate AND @FilterEndDate
),
cumulative AS (
  SELECT
    Date,
    ItemsOpened,
    ItemsOpenedCumulative = ItemsOpened
  FROM grouped
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    g.Date,
    g.ItemsOpened,
    ItemsOpenedCumulative = g.ItemsOpenedCumulative + c.ItemsOpened
  FROM grouped g
    INNER JOIN cumulative c ON g.Date = DATEADD(day, 1, c.Date)
)
SELECT *
FROM cumulative
```

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error in the above. "WITH cumulative AS" should be simply "cumulative AS"